# NSURL custom scheme trouble

Tags: ios6, uiwebview, nsurl

I wrote below code to programmatically load a URL in UIWebview.

```
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"app-api://camera_button(%@)", @"{\"date\":\"2014-05-26\",\"referer_url\":\"http://google.com",\"abort_url\":\"http://google.com"}"];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]]];
```

And in the webView's delegate method webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: , I found the url being loaded has been changed to 'file://app-api://......'. But what I needed is 'app-api:......'. Anyone can tell me what the problem is ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if problem in URL string, then use following code (**`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`**)

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL_STRING"];
NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

**EDITED**

You can remove *file://*  from your url string by using following code

```
NSString *selectedRequest = "MY URL STRING";
NSString *requestString = [selectedRequest stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *finalString = [requestString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", finalString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it does not work. The URL is stile begin with 'file://'.

Comment: Ok, it works. But, I want to know why that URL has been changed. String replacing is the way I don't want to use.

Comment: @Sabbath - sorry but i don't know why this is happing, If my answer is helpful for you then please accept it. :) Thanks :)